# Is it possible to include all Thrust headers at once?

Tags: cuda, thrust

Is there a way to include all Thrust files instead of doing it individually? For example, right now I have to do the following:

```
#include <thrust/version.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h> 
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
```

I just want to use something like

```
#include <thrust.h>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want that? You could always create your own header which simply includes all the others, but I would seriously advice against that.

Comment: Whether or not you can do it it one question, but whether or not you should do it is a very different question.

Comment: It's not a good idea because it would take much longer than necessary to compile your project.

Comment: In practice, I'm not sure there would be much difference because Thrust internally contains so many self-dependencies. It would be good to know for sure, though.

Comment: So it'd really slow down the compilation process? Thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no `<thrust/everything.h>` or equivalent header, so if you want this kind of functionality, you'd need to build it yourself as Bart suggests.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://pastebin.com/RDmxiYCi
```

Includes everything except thrust/system subfolder. Something like this

```
#include <thrust/adjacent_difference.h>
#include <thrust/advance.h>
#include <thrust/binary_search.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
...
```